# detect when all components or pages or router-outlet are fully loaded angular2

Tags: angular

Is possible to detect when all components or pages or router-outlet are fully loaded angular2, I mean everything and do this detection from the main app component or a specific component?

What is happening angular2 loads in 2 steps

1st the loading... text or graphic from the main index.html, then when the main component is loaded this text disappear and then the app wait to load all the router-outlet and then only then the app is loaded, depending if you are using lazy load or not.

So my question again, is possible to detect when everything has been loaded in angular2?

With a boolean? true or not...

Comment: angular does not know if the components are loaded or not, it's your job to maintain the state inside each component. But note that there are some activate/deactivate events on [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html#!#component-anchor) when the component is instanciated/removed...

Comment: That's not entirely true @n00dl3 there are lifecycle hooks that do give insight on this. eg. `AfterViewInit` on your root will fire after your child views load supposedly. I found this question while researching how to know which child components are loaded...

Comment: Yes but that does not mean async data is loaded and i think that's what op meant. However question is unclear...